# DropdownList with Selection and Clear Option (Glyphicon remove circle)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, listbox

I want to approach the below criteria:
 showing the list of possible options when list is expanded and ability to clear the selected value by providing clear option next to the selected value.Any Idea how to get on this one? (Attached are images for reference)

Opening my List of item when clicking on glyphicon:

[image: Opening my List of item when clicking on glyphicon]

After Selected any one of the item, I need some thing like the below image

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this one in dropdownlist or if there is any control to get on this one!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Surely you have done more than taking some pictures from different sites? Provide some code.

Comment: @Ozan Here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bseth99/dJDHd/ .Well, I took some pictures from different sites to understand my question bit easy (those are just sample references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a `glyphicon` when you change the text of the `dropdown`. And then reset the `dropdown`'s text when the `glyphicon` is clicked.

Since you have went through the trouble of creating a custom styled dropdown so that everything fits in little `panel`s, I am assuming you use it so this was made to fit in with them. If you want to use for other styles, you'll need to play with widths and positioning so that they don't overlap.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy34j5zr/1/)

**Javascript**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li', function (event) {

    var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
        $bg = $target.closest('.btn-group');

    $bg.find('[data-bind="label"]').text($target.text())
        .end()
        .children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

    if (!$bg.next("i.deselect").length) {
        $("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle deselect'>").insertAfter($bg);
        $bg.width($bg.width() - 25);
    }

    return false;

});

$(document).on("click", "i.deselect", function () {
    var $bg = $(this).prev(".btn-group");
    $bg.width($bg.width() + 25)
        .find('[data-bind="label"]').text("Select One");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-input {
    display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
    left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
}

i.deselect {
    float: right;
    margin: -26px -5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate!! I can adjust the position styling of the text.